# Sql Update command used in play framework (scala) does not seem to be working

Tags: sql, scala, jdbc, playframework

I have my Sql table setup as follows

```
create table contact(
id                      bigint not null,
first_name                varchar(255) not null,
last_name                 varchar(255) not null,
phone                     varchar(255) not null,
email                     varchar(255) not null,
company                   varchar(255) not null,
external_access           varchar(255),
online_status             varchar(12),
constraint pk_computer primary key (id));
```

So initially i input data values into the table except for external_access and online_status.Then I try to update online_status using the function below.

```
DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
SQL(
  """
     update contact
     set online_status = online
     where email = {email}
  """
     ).on(
       'email -> email
         ).executeUpdate()
  }
```

So after the online status is updated, I try to display the page again by using

```
  select * from contact
```

(The above code is just the gist. Actual display function is the page display function List of https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/scala/computer-database/app/models/Models.scala)

However, the online_status is not yet updated. It continues to display nothing(in the online_status column). Can someone help me debug this

Answer (score 0):

Online status is a varchar, problably your query should be like:

```
 """
     update contact
     set online_status = 'online'
     where email = {email}
  """
```

Notice the '' to define the value as string.

Also, make sure you are not storing the old values in a cache.

Comment: I tried the 'online' thing. Didn't make a difference. How can I make sure about the old values being stored in cache? Is there a way to check that and not allow it to happen (May be like volatile or something.. not really sure)